# Unnecessary space in Postman

Tags: api, post, space, postman

Hi I've got issue in Postman, I'm loading csv file and send POST request to db to insert some values:
In csv the value is "1699884692"
but in JSON after running the value is " 1699884692"
The char limit is set to 10 and "400: Bad request" appears. 
What can i do with it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok the problem was trivial, I've just make few columns and place each value in column instead of coma divission.